# Why no explicit casting is required while assigning int to char

Tags: java

In the code below:

```
char c = (char)64; //1
char c1 = 64;       //2

char c2 = (int)64;  //3
System.out.print((int)c2);//4.prints 64
System.out.print(c2);//5.prints @
```

1. Line 1: Compiles fine. no problem.
2. Line 2 : Attempting downcast implicitly. It compiles fine. Why not compile time error?
3. Line 3: Compiles fine. Again, why not CT error?
4. Line 4: Prints 64 as it should. No problem.
5. Line 5: Why should it print `@`. I know that `@` corresponds to `ASCII` value 64. But we have explicit casted it `(int)64`. Why it is behaving like `c2 = (ASCII)64*`?

*my made up syntax

Comment: `System.out.print` work perfectly in your case. If you look a bit at line 3, you told the compiler that the left hand variable type is `char` and it takes the value `(int )64`. What you wrote is exactly equal to `char c2 = 64`. Because the variable is `char`, the output will be `@`

Comment: @Justplayit94 Thats is exactly my question. If it stores 64. It should print 64 as well. Why is it printing @ corresponding to ASCII 64.

Comment: The answer is in your code. If you want it to print `64`, you change the last line to `System.out.print((int)c2);`

Comment: @SKG you stored it in a `char`.  It's always going to be a char, not an integer.

Comment: "I know that @ corresponds to ASCII value 64": Well, actually `char` is a UTF-16 code unit, the one UTF-16 code unit with the value 64 is the complete encoding for the Uncode codepoint 64 ([U+0040](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0040/index.htm)), which when output with `print` gets encoded into Java's selection for the default encoding for the system, which when decoded by your console's actual encoding and rendered using your console's font, displays as `@`. ASCII doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: And you aren't assigning. You are initializing.